# How to install software from 14.10 repositories?

Tags: apt, updates, software-installation, kdevelop

At work I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS) with KDevelop IDE. I saw there is a new version of KDevelop available, 4.7 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdevelop). On my computer I have version 4.6 installed.

After trying `sudo apt-get install kdevelop` it reports I already have the latest version. Why is this? Do I need to add the 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) repository to be able to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not simply mix packages from different releases (as you may in Gentoo). 
Your two options are:

- Fully upgrade to unicorn
- Use backports, if there are any. [Here is about them](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports).